# Xcode giving version compatibility warning for unknown reason

Tags: ios, xcode, version, warnings, compatibility

I think the two screen-shots make this question self-explanatory.

Am I taking crazy pills here?  Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the _Deployment Target_ of your _Project_. Check the value for the _Target_.

Comment: Oh no!  Should I delete the question or post an answer to myself?

Comment: Sure! (8 more to go)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `Deployment Target` of your project. Check the value for the `Target`. Just delete the value in the target setting than the target will inherit the value from the project.

Answer (score 1):

> You got this error because your version is lowest. so, you can add
>   this code on top of your function if you want to run your app in
>   lowest version.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func youFunctionName() {

}
```

> if you want to run your app in letest version you can do it. 
>   select your project -> General -> Targets -> Deployment Info -> Deployment
>   Targets -> 10.0